# Sed Command substitution how do you treat spaces or multiple spaces as one?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I use this command to insert a line. If  there is a space in the pattern between two entries in the text or file it prints the content on the new line. It works fine, however sometimes I encounter 2 spaces or 3 spaces instead of one that I'm looking for in the pattern so I get additional blank lines.

```
sed "s/ /\n/g"
```

I want to print a new line only the sed finds something in the pattern.
How should I use the sed command to treat 1 space or double or triple spaces as one substitute?

Comment: I know this is a sed question. But it can be achieve by `tr -s ' ' '\n'`

Comment: And also by `awk '$1=$1' OFS='\n'`

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im There is little point in adding an option in the comments after it has been specified in one of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a quantifier:

```
sed "s/  */\n/g"
```

or

```
sed 's/ \+/\n/g'       # With GNU sed
```

or

```
sed -r 's/ +/\n/g'
```

or

```
sed 's/ \{1,\}/\n/g'
```

or

```
sed -r 's/ {1,}/\n/g'
```

---

If using BSD sed,

```
sed 's/  */\'$'\n''/g'
```

or

```
sed -r 's/ +/\'$'\n''/g'
```

---

You could also use `tr`:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n'
```

The `-s` option *squeezes* repeats of a character in set1, i.e. the `' '` in this example.

Comment: second one is not portable.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Thanks added a note.  Added options for BSD sed too.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like...

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' [filename]
```

To find and replace one or more white space with a new line.